# Install pyvasp: how to compile vasp 6.2.0 with hdf5 support

Tags: vasp

The following makefile.include was supplied to me, which was used for an existing installation of vasp 6.2.0 without hdf5 support. I am trying to modify it to recompile vasp with hdf5 support, in order to be able to use py4vasp.

```
# Precompiler options
CPP_OPTIONS= -DHOST=\"LinuxIFC\"\
             -DMPI -DMPI_BLOCK=8000 -Duse_collective \
             -DscaLAPACK \
             -DCACHE_SIZE=4000 \
             -Davoidalloc \
             -Dvasp6 \
             -Duse_bse_te \
             -Dtbdyn \
             -Dfock_dblbuf

CPP        = fpp -f_com=no -free -w0  $*$(FUFFIX) $*$(SUFFIX) $(CPP_OPTIONS)

FC         = mpiifort
FCL        = mpiifort -mkl=sequential

FREE       = -free -names lowercase

FFLAGS     = -assume byterecl -w -xHOST
OFLAG      = -O2
OFLAG_IN   = $(OFLAG)
DEBUG      = -O0

MKL_PATH   = $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64
BLAS       =
LAPACK     =
BLACS      = -lmkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64
SCALAPACK  = $(MKL_PATH)/libmkl_scalapack_lp64.a $(BLACS)

OBJECTS    = fftmpiw.o fftmpi_map.o fft3dlib.o fftw3d.o

INCS       =-I$(MKLROOT)/include/fftw

LLIBS      = $(SCALAPACK) $(LAPACK) $(BLAS)

OBJECTS_O1 += fftw3d.o fftmpi.o fftmpiw.o
OBJECTS_O2 += fft3dlib.o

# For what used to be vasp.5.lib
CPP_LIB    = $(CPP)
FC_LIB     = $(FC)
CC_LIB     = icc
CFLAGS_LIB = -O
FFLAGS_LIB = -O1
FREE_LIB   = $(FREE)

OBJECTS_LIB= linpack_double.o getshmem.o

# For the parser library
CXX_PARS   = icpc
LLIBS      += -lstdc++

# Normally no need to change this
SRCDIR     = ../../src
BINDIR     = ../../bin

#================================================
# GPU Stuff

CPP_GPU    = -DCUDA_GPU -DRPROMU_CPROJ_OVERLAP -DUSE_PINNED_MEMORY -DCUFFT_MIN=28 -UscaLAPACK -Ufock_dblbuf

OBJECTS_GPU= fftmpiw.o fftmpi_map.o fft3dlib.o fftw3d_gpu.o fftmpiw_gpu.o

CC         = icc
CXX        = icpc
CFLAGS     = -fPIC -DADD_ -Wall -qopenmp -DMAGMA_WITH_MKL -DMAGMA_SETAFFINITY -DGPUSHMEM=300 -DHAVE_CUBLAS

# Minimal requirement is CUDA >= 10.X. For "sm_80" you need CUDA >= 11.X.
CUDA_ROOT  ?= /usr/local/cuda/
NVCC       := $(CUDA_ROOT)/bin/nvcc -ccbin=icc -allow-unsupported-compiler
CUDA_LIB   := -L$(CUDA_ROOT)/lib64 -lnvToolsExt -lcudart -lcuda -lcufft -lcublas

GENCODE_ARCH    := -gencode=arch=compute_60,code=\"sm_60,compute_60\" \
                   -gencode=arch=compute_70,code=\"sm_70,compute_70\" \
                   -gencode=arch=compute_80,code=\"sm_80,compute_80\"

## For all legacy Intel MPI versions (before 2021)
#MPI_INC    = $(I_MPI_ROOT)/intel64/include/

# Or when you are using the Intel oneAPI compiler suite
MPI_INC    = $(I_MPI_ROOT)/include/
```

I appended these lines as explained in [1]

```
#Needed for py4vasp
CPP_OPTIONS+= -DVASP_HDF5
HDF5_ROOT  ?= /home/myname/hdf/HDF5-1.12.1-Linux/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.12.1
LLIBS      += -L$(HDF5_ROOT)/lib -lhdf5_fortran
INCS       += -I$(HDF5_ROOT)/include
```

Adding these lines caused the following errors

```
 
:: initializing oneAPI environment ...
   slurm_script: BASH_VERSION = 5.1.4(1)-release
:: advisor -- latest
:: ccl -- latest
:: clck -- latest
:: compiler -- latest
:: dal -- latest
:: debugger -- latest
:: dev-utilities -- latest
:: dnnl -- latest
:: dpcpp-ct -- latest
:: dpl -- latest
:: inspector -- latest
:: intelpython -- latest
:: ipp -- latest
:: ippcp -- latest
:: ipp -- latest
:: itac -- latest
:: mkl -- latest
:: mpi -- latest
:: tbb -- latest
:: vpl -- latest
:: vtune -- latest
:: oneAPI environment initialized ::
 
if [ ! -d build/std ] ; then mkdir build/std  ; fi;
cp src/makefile src/.objects src/makedeps.awk makefile.include build/std ;
make -C build/std VERSION=std cleandependencies -j1
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std'
rm -f .depend
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std'
make -C build/std VERSION=std all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std'
rsync -ru ../../src/lib .
cp makefile.include lib
make -C lib -j1
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/lib'
make libdmy.a
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/lib'
make[3]: 'libdmy.a' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/lib'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/lib'
rsync -ru ../../src/parser .
cp makefile.include parser
make -C parser -j1
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/parser'
make libparser.a
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/parser'
make[3]: 'libparser.a' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/parser'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/parser'
rsync -u ../../src/*.F ../../src/*.inc .
rm -f vasp ; make vasp ; cp vasp ../../bin/vasp_std
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std'
mpiifort -free -names lowercase -assume byterecl -w -xHOST -O2 -I/home/software/materia/intel_lib/mkl/2021.4.0/include/fftw -I/home/myname/hdf/HDF5-1.12.1-Linux/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.12.1/include  -c vhdf5_base.f90
vhdf5_base.F(6): error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [HDF5]
  use hdf5
------^
vhdf5_base.F(36): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T):: ih5intermediategroup_id
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(37): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T):: ih5infileid
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(38): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T):: ih5outfileid
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(39): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T):: ih5wavefileid
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(40): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T):: ih5ininputgroup_id
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(41): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T):: ih5outinputgroup_id
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(42): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T):: ih5outoriginalgroup_id
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(57): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T) :: create_inter_prop
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(204): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) :: fileid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(218): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) :: fileid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(232): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) :: fileid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(247): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) :: fileid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(263): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) :: fileid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(274): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) :: fileid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(316): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) :: fileid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(344): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) ::   locid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(346): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) ::  groupid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(357): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) ::   groupid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(370): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) ::   locid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(372): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) ::  groupid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(387): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) ::   locid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(389): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) ::  groupid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(410): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) ::   groupid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(426): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) :: locid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(451): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) :: groupid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(457): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T) :: dset_id, attr_id, aspace, string_type
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(458): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HSIZE_T]
    integer(HSIZE_T) :: dimensions(1)
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(459): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HSIZE_T]
    integer(HSIZE_T) :: strlen
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(500): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) :: locid
------------^
vhdf5_base.f90(2776): catastrophic error: Too many errors, exiting
compilation aborted for vhdf5_base.f90 (code 1)
make[2]: *** [makefile:181: vhdf5_base.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std'
cp: cannot stat 'vasp': No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [makefile:146: all] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std'
make: *** [makefile:9: std] Error 2
```

I am using a virtual machine Linux #1 SMP Debian 5.10.140-1 (2022-09-02), where I installed
hdf5-1.12.1-Std-ubuntu2010_64.tar.gz from [2].

[1]: https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Makefile.include#HDF5_support_.28strongly_recommended.29)
[2]: https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/releases/hdf5-1.12/hdf5-1.12.1/bin/unix/

EDIT: Now I have tried building HDF5 from source rather than using the binary file, following these steps:

```
         gunzip < hdf5-1.14.0.tar.gz | tar xf -
         cd hdf5-1.14.0
         ./configure --enable-fortran --enable-cxx
         make
         make check                # run test suite.
         make install
         make check-install        # verify installation
```

After updating the HDF5_ROOT in vasp makefile.include, now the compiling job returns the following errors:

```
:: initializing oneAPI environment ...
   slurm_script: BASH_VERSION = 5.1.4(1)-release
:: advisor -- latest
:: ccl -- latest
:: clck -- latest
:: compiler -- latest
:: dal -- latest
:: debugger -- latest
:: dev-utilities -- latest
:: dnnl -- latest
:: dpcpp-ct -- latest
:: dpl -- latest
:: inspector -- latest
:: intelpython -- latest
:: ipp -- latest
:: ippcp -- latest
:: ipp -- latest
:: itac -- latest
:: mkl -- latest
:: mpi -- latest
:: tbb -- latest
:: vpl -- latest
:: vtune -- latest
:: oneAPI environment initialized ::
 
if [ ! -d build/std ] ; then mkdir build/std  ; fi;
cp src/makefile src/.objects src/makedeps.awk makefile.include build/std ;
make -C build/std VERSION=std cleandependencies -j1
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std'
rm -f .depend
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std'
make -C build/std VERSION=std all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std'
rsync -ru ../../src/lib .
cp makefile.include lib
make -C lib -j1
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/lib'
make libdmy.a
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/lib'
make[3]: 'libdmy.a' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/lib'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/lib'
rsync -ru ../../src/parser .
cp makefile.include parser
make -C parser -j1
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/parser'
make libparser.a
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/parser'
make[3]: 'libparser.a' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/parser'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/parser'
rsync -u ../../src/*.F ../../src/*.inc .
rm -f vasp ; make vasp ; cp vasp ../../bin/vasp_std
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std'
mpiifort -free -names lowercase -assume byterecl -w -xHOST -O2 -I/home/software/materia/intel_lib/mkl/2021.4.0/include/fftw -I/home/myname/hdf5-1.14.0/hdf5/include  -c vhdf5_base.f90
vhdf5_base.F(6): error #7013: This module file was not generated by any release of this compiler.   [HDF5]
  use hdf5
------^
vhdf5_base.F(36): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T):: ih5intermediategroup_id
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(37): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T):: ih5infileid
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(38): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T):: ih5outfileid
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(39): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T):: ih5wavefileid
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(40): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T):: ih5ininputgroup_id
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(41): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T):: ih5outinputgroup_id
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(42): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T):: ih5outoriginalgroup_id
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(57): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T) :: create_inter_prop
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(204): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) :: fileid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(218): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) :: fileid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(232): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) :: fileid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(247): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) :: fileid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(263): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) :: fileid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(274): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) :: fileid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(316): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) :: fileid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(344): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) ::   locid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(346): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) ::  groupid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(357): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) ::   groupid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(370): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) ::   locid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(372): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) ::  groupid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(387): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) ::   locid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(389): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) ::  groupid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(410): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) ::   groupid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(426): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) :: locid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(451): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) :: groupid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(457): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T) :: dset_id, attr_id, aspace, string_type
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(458): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HSIZE_T]
    integer(HSIZE_T) :: dimensions(1)
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(459): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HSIZE_T]
    integer(HSIZE_T) :: strlen
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(500): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) :: locid
------------^
vhdf5_base.f90(2776): catastrophic error: Too many errors, exiting
compilation aborted for vhdf5_base.f90 (code 1)
make[2]: *** [makefile:181: vhdf5_base.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std'
cp: cannot stat 'vasp': No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [makefile:146: all] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std'
make: *** [makefile:9: std] Error 2
```

EDIT2: Following @IanBush 's suggestion I have recompiled HDF5 with

```
CXX=icpc CC=icc FC=ifort ./configure --enable-fortran --enable-cxx; make -j 4
make check 
make install
make check-install
```

but again when compiling vasp I obtained errors about the include path (I have checked that the directory HDF5_ROOT   ?= /home/myname/hdf5-1.14.0/hdf5 actually contains include folder)

````
if [ ! -d build/std ] ; then mkdir build/std  ; fi;
cp src/makefile src/.objects src/makedeps.awk makefile.include build/std ;
make -C build/std VERSION=std cleandependencies -j1
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std'
rm -f .depend
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std'
make -C build/std VERSION=std all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std'
rsync -ru ../../src/lib .
cp makefile.include lib
make -C lib -j1
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/lib'
make libdmy.a
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/lib'
make[3]: 'libdmy.a' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/lib'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/lib'
rsync -ru ../../src/parser .
cp makefile.include parser
make -C parser -j1
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/parser'
make libparser.a
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/parser'
make[3]: 'libparser.a' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/parser'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std/parser'
rsync -u ../../src/*.F ../../src/*.inc .
rm -f vasp ; make vasp ; cp vasp ../../bin/vasp_std
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std'
mpiifort -free -names lowercase -assume byterecl -w -xHOST -O2 -I/home/software/materia/intel_lib/mkl/2021.4.0/include/fftw -I/home/myname/hdf5-1.14.0/hdf5/include  -c vhdf5_base.f90
vhdf5_base.F(6): error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [HDF5]
  use hdf5
------^
vhdf5_base.F(36): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T):: ih5intermediategroup_id
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(37): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T):: ih5infileid
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(38): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T):: ih5outfileid
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(39): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T):: ih5wavefileid
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(40): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T):: ih5ininputgroup_id
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(41): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T):: ih5outinputgroup_id
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(42): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T):: ih5outoriginalgroup_id
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(57): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(HID_T) :: create_inter_prop
----------^
vhdf5_base.F(204): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) :: fileid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(218): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) :: fileid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(232): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) :: fileid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(247): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) :: fileid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(263): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) :: fileid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(274): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) :: fileid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(316): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) :: fileid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(344): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) ::   locid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(346): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) ::  groupid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(357): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) ::   groupid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(370): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) ::   locid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(372): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) ::  groupid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(387): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) ::   locid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(389): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(out) ::  groupid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(410): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) ::   groupid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(426): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) :: locid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(451): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) :: groupid
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(457): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T) :: dset_id, attr_id, aspace, string_type
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(458): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HSIZE_T]
    integer(HSIZE_T) :: dimensions(1)
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(459): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HSIZE_T]
    integer(HSIZE_T) :: strlen
------------^
vhdf5_base.F(500): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
    integer(HID_T), intent(in) :: locid
------------^
vhdf5_base.f90(2776): catastrophic error: Too many errors, exiting
compilation aborted for vhdf5_base.f90 (code 1)
make[2]: *** [makefile:181: vhdf5_base.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std'
cp: cannot stat 'vasp': No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [makefile:146: all] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/vasp.6.2.0/build/std'
make: *** [makefile:9: std] Error 2

```
````

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here. We hope to see much more of you!!! Can you confirm that you have HDF5 installed on this VM? The error tells you to "check your INCLUDE paths". Perhaps you need to install HDF5 and include a path to it so that the compiler knows where HDF5 is located on the VM? On the Compute Canada machines you can just type `module load hdf5` before doing the compiling, because HDF5 is already instaslled as a module.

Comment: Thank you! I have unzipped hdf5-1.12.1-Std-ubuntu2010_64.tar.gz , then executed `./HDF5-1.12.1-Linux.sh` in hdf folder and looked for the folder containing include, which I then assigned to HDF5_ROOT in the makefile.include, then added `INCS  += -I$(HDF5_ROOT)/include` as written above. Are there additional needed steps for the installation? Or is it possible that I'm using an incompatible binary and I should build from source instead? (I'm not very familiar with how to select options to build from source, which is why is tried with a binary file)

Comment: @NikeDattani Since I wasn't sure about HDF5 being installed correctly from binary file, I have now built it from source and edited the post. Now vasp compiling job says:
`vhdf5_base.F(6): error #7013: This module file was not generated by any release of this compiler.   [HDF5]
  use hdf5`

Comment: From what you have done it is likely (but I can't know for cerrtain) that you are compiling hdf5 with gcc. This will produce a module file that is incompatible with the Intel Fortran compiler - hence "vhdf5_base.F(6): error #7013: This module file was not generated by any release of this compiler.  " You need to compile hdf5 with the Intel compiler, or VASP with the gnu compiler. Don't try mixing the two. I haven't compiled hfd5 with the intel compiler but what happens if you try `CC=icc FC=ifort ./configure --enable-fortran --enable-cxx`

Comment: OK, back at my computer. On my machine `CXX=icpc CC=icc FC=ifort ./configure --enable-fortran --enable-cxx; make -j 4` successfully builds hdf5-1.14.0 with the Intel compiler and provides an hdf5.mod that the Intel compiler can use. I can't test against VASP as I don't have access to the source code, hence a comment rather than an answer, but  `make check` passes all tests.

Comment: You might want to use `make -j2` or just `make` if you're on a personal computer. I froze a laptop for over an hour by using `make -j4` when installing OpenMolcas :) By the way, what is the reason why you need hdf5 support?

Comment: In the directory /home/myname/hdf5-1.14.0 what does `find . -name hdf5.mod -print` tell you?

Comment: @NikeDattani Thanks, actually I'm using the college cluster. Compiling vasp with hdf5 support is required to install py4vasp, to plot bandstructure projected on atoms.

Comment: @IanBush It doesn't find anything...

Comment: @we_are_always_learning Well there is your problem. I found it strange that you set HDF5_ROOT to that directory as make install may well move the files out of there. FYI before I do make install on my machine hdf5.mod is in hdf5-14.1.0/fortran/src/hdf5.mod - assuming your make was successful you will have to work up where it ended and make sure it is part of the -I list on the compile line.

Comment: Since this is being installed on your college cluster, there might already be an HDF5 module installed. This is done because colleges have 100s if not 1000s of people, so it doesn't make sense for each of them to install HDF5 separately (this would waste too much space). What's the name of your college cluster?

Comment: @NikeDattani I have found that 1) by setting `INCS   += -I/usr/include/hdf5/serial ` (and leaving the library directory unchanged), which is the folder where hdf5.mod has been already installed on the cluster, I get the error vhdf5_base.F(6): error #7013: This module file was not generated by any release of this compiler.   [HDF5]
2) @IanBush if I try to locate the hdf5 module in my home folder  `find . -iname "hdf5.mod"`, I cannot find it in the directory of intel compilation.

Comment: @IanBush 3) On the other hand, the module is correctly found for the first installation I had tried (from binary file) and for the second installation (compiled from source with default compiler), but these give error when compiling vasp with intel compiler, as you had explained above.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but now that it has been almost 1 year, can you update us please? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Did you figure it out after all this time?